# zeep soap12 wsdl+mtom+wsse how to make request?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep, wsse

TPA.wsdl https://pastebin.com/7DBhCHbv
DataService.xsd  https://pastebin.com/AFhg64hH

---

```
from zeep import Client
import base64
from requests import Session
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.exceptions import Fault
Username = '....'
Password = '....'
sendFile = 'V07_220110.ffdata'

session = Session()
session.verify = False
try:
    wsdl = 'TPA.wsdl'

    # initialize zeep client
    client = Client(
    wsdl=wsdl,
    wsse=UsernameToken(Username, Password),
    transport=Transport(session=session)
    )

    with open(sendFile, "rb") as pdf_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())
    with client.options(raw_response=True):
        node = client.service.uploadEdasDraft(sendFile, encoded_string )
        print(node.content)

except Fault as fault:
    parsed_fault_detail = client.wsdl.types.deserialize(fault.detail[0])
```

---

Always getting Response

I got error ORA-31011: XML parsing failed

From SOAPUI everything sending ok with Enable MTOM settings

So how to make request to it, and how debug sending requests?

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoint right after the call? You catch all the errors in one generic block, so it might be something related to the contents or something with the call in general. I would suggest adding a breakpoint right after client initialisation and from there step through the code.

Comment: how add breakpoint in python?

Comment: Assuming you run this commandline. Python2: import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

Comment: Python3(.6 and up I believe): breakpoint()

Comment: Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: but zeep have no trace info

Comment: https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html?highlight=debug#debugging

Official documentation says otherwise ;)

Comment: but how to view sended requests?

Comment: Why do you want that? Apart from the breakpoint right after sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on that WSDL file, a code like this:

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken

username = 'username'
password = 'p@$$word'
file_name = 'test.txt'

client = Client(wsdl = 'TPA.wsdl', 
                wsse = UsernameToken(username, password))

with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
    content = f.read()

client.service.uploadEdasDraft(file_name, content)
```

should produce something like this:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap-env:Header>
     <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
           <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
           <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">p@$$word</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
     </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
     <ns0:uploadEdasDraft xmlns:ns0="http://types.data.external.ws.edas.sodra.epr.lt">
        <fileName>test.txt</fileName>
        <document>dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QNCnRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0DQp0aGlzIGlzIGEgdGVzdA0KdGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QNCg==</document>
     </ns0:uploadEdasDraft>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Since the document type is marked as `xsd:base64Binary` zeep should handle the base64 encoding for you (your code seems to be doing the encoding twice).

In the example above I'm using a text file, but I assume your file named `V07_220110.ffdata` is an XML file, since that's what this attribute says: `xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/xml"`. Server will probably complain if you don't send a file with this content type. This may also be a possible cause for that "ORA-31011: XML parsing failed" message, together with the double encoding (server is expecting XML in the document but finds another base64 string).

> From SOAPUI everything sending ok with Enable MTOM settings

When using MTOM, your file is not encoded within the SOAP message as text, but it's attached as binary next to it, and you get references to that part of the message. See an explanation here: [How does MTOM work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215741/how-does-mtom-work)

Your document element might change to something like:

```
<document>
  <inc:Include href="cid:123456789" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
</document>
```

where `123456789` is a reference to the content id in the multipart message.

Does your call work from SoapUI only if you enable MTOM? Have you tried sending a base64 encoded file string within the SOAP message using SoapUI?

If your call only works with MTOM then you have a problem, because I'm not sure zeep can handle it out of the box.

The documentation (https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/attachments.html) mentions only a multipart response and how you can read the file from the response, but says nothing about making requests. See for example these items:

- https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/599
- https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/pull/314
- https://github.com/remaudcorentin-dev/python-zeep-adv

The last project might help you with some code samples (https://github.com/remaudcorentin-dev/python-zeep-adv/blob/master/src/zeep/transport_with_attach.py) but do consider the caveat:

> This has been developed for a specific usage and this code should probably not be used (has it) for other puposes.
> (or at your own risks ;) )

So it seems you might have to build your own multipart request from scratch or from that sample in the project.

> [...] and how debug sending requests?

You might use the [HistoryPlugin](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html) just to see what messages get exchanged between your client and server, but since you might need to see all of the request, I suggest [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [TcpMon](https://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/) (old, defunct, but still useful), or [SoapUI with TcpMon](https://www.soapui.org/docs/http-recording/reference/http-monitor/).

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but hope that at least it leaves you more equipped in figuring out how to make the call. Zeep unfortunately is a small fish client in [a large pond of WS specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications).

Comment: Ty, can you write a piece of code with mtom sending from python? or how to use python-zeep-adv, as no manuals exists

Comment: I'm sorry but writing a full implementation goes beyond the time I'm willing to allocate to participate in the Stackoverflow community. You have to troubleshoot this on your own with the help I have provided. But before you do that, do you really need to write a MTOM implementation? In other words, have you done what I mentioned in the first half of my answer? Are you making sure to send a proper attachment? Have you made sure you encode the file only once in base64? Have you tried this kind of call from SoapUI? Like I said, based on that WSDL, a simpler call should work without MTOM.