# Sending MTOM SOAP attachment Via Python Zeep or SUDS or any other way

Tags: python-3.x, wsdl, suds, zeep, mtom

I have been browsing and have not been able to find a way to send MTOM attachments, whether it is via SUDS or Zeep python libraries. I see that Zeep allows the reading of [MTOM attachments](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/attachments.html). But not the attachment and send.

Essentially, I already have the raw bytes, but I am trying to send them as an attachment rather than attaching all of the bytes to an object I then send to a service function.

Comment: With zeep, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721577) contains some links that might provide some help, but frankly speaking, you are pretty much on your own.

Comment: Hi, did you have any success? Could you please Share your results