# WCF service with MTOM attachment post request return "Error creating a reader for the MTOM message"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, soap

I have a WCF serivce that receives a soap message from a client, simple post Service Contract that receives message with MTOM file attachment.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/schema/service/Upload/1.0")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IBillerReconcileNotificationService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "Reconcile")]
    [FaultContract(typeof(BillerNotificationFault))]
    UploadMsgRs Reconcile(UploadMsgRq requestModel);
}

public class BillerReconcileNotificationService : IBillerReconcileNotificationService
{ 
    public UploadMsgRs Reconcile(UploadMsgRq requestModel)
    {//handling request business}
}
```

While testing the service by sending a request in postman I always received 400 bad request response, WCF trace log show the following exception :

```
**<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Error creating a reader for the MTOM message</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.MtomBufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageData.GetMessageReader()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.ContinueReading(Int32 bytesRead)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.DecodeBufferedMessageAsync()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.BeginParse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.BeginParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginParseIncomingMessage(AsyncCallback asynCallback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error creating a reader for the MTOM message ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Root MIME part containing infoset not found.
   at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.ReadRootMimePart()
   at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.Initialize(Stream stream, String contentType, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, Int32 maxBufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.SetInput(Stream stream, Encoding[] encodings, String contentType, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, Int32 maxBufferSize, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.MtomBufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Root MIME part containing infoset not found.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.ReadRootMimePart()
at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.Initialize(Stream stream, String contentType, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, Int32 maxBufferSize)
at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.SetInput(Stream stream, Encoding[] encodings, String contentType, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, Int32 maxBufferSize, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.MtomBufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: Root MIME part containing infoset not found.
   at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.ReadRootMimePart()
   at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.Initialize(Stream stream, String contentType, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, Int32 maxBufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.SetInput(Stream stream, Encoding[] encodings, String contentType, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, Int32 maxBufferSize, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.MtomBufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()</ExceptionString>
</InnerException>
</Exception>**
```

Note: I'm using multipart/related Content-Type request header as following : `multipart/related; boundary=3f9d206f-1054-4731-b737-6e724723832a; start-info="text/xml"; type="application/xop+xml"`

In configuration file it really simple wcf service configuration with basicHttpBinding inplace :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="BPNotificationWeb.Services.BillerReconcileNotificationService" behaviorConfiguration="ReconcileHttpBindingBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          contract="BPNotificationWeb.Services.IBillerReconcileNotificationService"
                          bindingConfiguration="httpBinding">
                </endpoint>
            </service>
</services>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="httpBinding"  messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"></binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="BillerNotificationHttpBindingBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I guess I'm missing something here any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have similar issue here, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215741/how-does-mtom-work This post tells you how MTOM works and I think it can helpe you.